# How accurate is the suggestion given by Dynamic Management View for Index Tuning

Tags: sql-server, dmv

Some index suggestions can be found from

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details
```

How accurate is the index column suggest here we can rely on?
If not, is there any quick and better way to find some hints about indexing?

Comment: They're usually a pretty good starting point. Best thing as always is to try and see. Often if you put in place every recommended index you get way too many with some very similar. So you need to try and understand them.

Comment: *"quick and better way"*... if such a thing existed we would all have used it. Try some T-SQL books by Itzik Ben-Gan or , here is a website that you may find useful https://use-the-index-luke.com/